# Warping labels in tree plots

Tags: r, classification

I am using several tree plots (ctree, evtree, rpart, chaid) and I rely on categorical data. Levels of data are described with text labels. 
In plot, it is not clear whether the displayed text belongs to the left or right node.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/eqds3s/9]

Is it possible to either warp the text labels in plot, or provide slightly different vertical alignment for the text displayed in left and right node?

As requested, here is a code producing such an issue in the plot:

```
     <- data.frame(
  y = as.factor(sample(1:3,200,r=T)),
  x1 = as.factor(sample(1:3,200,r=T)),
  x2 = as.factor(sample(1:3,200,r=T)),
  x3 = as.factor(sample(1:3,200,r=T)),
  x4 = as.factor(sample(1:3,200,r=T))
)


Df1[1:5] <- lapply(Df1[1:5], function(x) factor(x, levels = c(1,2,3),labels = c("long long long long long text","text1","lorem ipsum dolor")))


library("partykit")
library("rpart")
library("evtree")
library("CHAID")


rp <- rpart(y ~ .,data=Df1, minbucket=30) 
plot(as.party(rp))
ct <- ctree(y~ . , data = Df1, minbucket=50)
plot(ct)
ev <- evtree(y ~ ., data = Df1, maxdepth = 5)
plot(ev)
ctrl <- chaid_control(minsplit=90, minbucket=30, minprob=0.05,alpha2=0.01, alpha3=-1, alpha4=0.01)
chaid1 <- chaid( y ~ ., data= Df1, control=ctrl)
plot(chaid1,cex=0.6)
```

Comment: Please add the code necessary to produce such a plot (it can be a small subset of data, or preferably, a simulated set).

Answer (score 0):

Can't see how this would be possible using parameters in `?plot.party`. You could, however, add `\n` (new line) to factor levels.

```
levels(Df1$x2)[1] <- "long long long \n long long text"
plot(as.party(rp))
```

[image]